# How can I remove cement board siding which is behind the soffit channel?

Tags: siding

I need to replace my siding and trying to decide whether to hire someone or not. I’ve done siding before but I’m wondering the easiest way to tear off the old siding when the J channel/soffit is over the last row.

The existing siding is CertainTeed Cement board. Anyone know how to and how difficult it will be to remove the last row without having to redo the soffit?

I would be replacing it with Hardie most likely. CertainTeed may be a reputable company with good products now, I don’t doubt that, but this siding was part of a class action lawsuit for being faulty. It’s shrinking, delaminating, and cracking like crazy.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Soffit is usually installed *before* siding, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. You would need to run something like a toe kick saw or an angle grinder (in a rather awkward manner) along the J-channel to cut it. Cement board doesn't cut easily and is messy. It won't be fun and has an element of danger. Use appropriate eye, ear, and respiration protection. Work from a stable platform.

Since you're replacing with like product, maybe just leave that top board and install the new siding under it. If it's not the same color, your new siding's manufacturer can provide a match.

Comment: Agreed. If you do end up cutting, maybe think about some chunky quarter round or square trim to cover the cut zone, which will reduce your need for extreme precision.